# Cannot open: http://rdo.Fedorapeople.org/openstack/openstack-grizzly/rdo-release-grizzly-1.noarch.rpm. Skipping

Tags: centos

In my Cent OS6.5, I want to install the below:

```
[root@localhost /]# yum install -y http://rdo.Fedorapeople.org/openstack/openstack-grizzly/rdo-release-grizzly-1.noarch.rpm
```

But I get the below information:

```
[root@localhost /]# yum install -y http://rdo.Fedorapeople.org/openstack/openstack-grizzly/rdo-release-grizzly-1.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * extras: mirrors.163.com
 * updates: mirrors.163.com
Setting up Install Process
Cannot open: http://rdo.Fedorapeople.org/openstack/openstack-grizzly/rdo-release-grizzly-1.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost /]#
```

How to fix it?

Comment: No such rpm exists in the address you're trying to install it from.

Comment: @n8te How can I add it?

Comment: Grizzly appears to be EOL. Do you need this particular version? How about installing the latest following the instructions [here](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/quickstart/)